# Dropped my database and Entity Framework seems unable to recreate it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I dropped my local database in order to verify that Entity Framework could successfully recreate it. It can't, even if it could before.

I have 3 custom migrations and it seems unable to recognize the first 2, so it tries to start from the 3rd one and as it can't find the tables it is trying to modify, it fails.

I have attempted:

```
update-database -TargetMigration:0
update-database
```

This fails with:

```
Applying explicit migrations: [201709191739089_third].
Applying explicit migration: 201709191739089_third.
Cannot find the object "dbo.Changes" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

I have attempted:

```
update-database -TargetMigration:201709041416046_first
The specified target migration '201709041416046_first' does not exist. Ensure that target migration refers to an existing migration id.
```

But if I try to explicitly run the 3rd migration, it does recognize its name:

```
update-database -TargetMigration:201709191739089_third
Applying explicit migrations: [201709191739089_third].
Applying explicit migration: 201709191739089_third.
```

It seems it lost track of my migrations and I can't find how to make it recognize the first two anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake.

The first and second migrations were originally created in a different namespace.

EF Migrations use the namespace to track which migrations are available.

So, in fact, since the change of namespace, the first and second migrations were never being executed, but we didn't notice it because all our databases had them already applied. When I dropped the database, the only migration that was in the correct namespace was the third, but its changes depended in the previous two, so it failed.

The fix was making sure that all migrations were in the same directory, under the same namespace.